# How to use JQuery's appendTo method with a long string of elements, containing combination of single/double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this content script that is returning data from my server to me, an array of objects and it basically looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "lang": "English",
    "videos": [
      {
        "embed": "<iframe width='100%' height='421px' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowfullscreen='true' webkitallowfullscreen='true' mozallowfullscreen='true' src='//example.com/embed/12355612312'></iframe>",
        "platform": "other",
        "video_id": "12355612312"
      },
      {
        "embed": "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
        "platform": "youtube",
        "video_id": "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see, the `embed` properties are different, one contains single quotes, the other one is double quotes.

Next I have a class that grabs that data, adds other HTML elements in between and finally returns a long string. For simplicity purposes, let's just use a function and assume it does this:

```
function(server_data) {
    return (
    '<div>\
        <input value=">' + server_data[0].videos[0].embed + '">\
        <input value="' + server_data[0].videos[1].embed + '">\
    </div>'
    )
}
```

Finally, I want to use JQuery to append that string of HTML to another element.

```
$(server_data(mydata)).appendTo('body');
```

The problem is that after I run this function, it breaks the HTML code because it doesn't recognize the escaped double quotes inside of it.

I know I could probably `encodeURIComponent()` each one of these values inside of my function, and after appending them to the DOM I run another for loop to decodeURI the values, but that seems like a dirty way of achieving something simple as this.

So my question is, is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: have you tried to replace \" with ' ?

Comment: you not need replace it but simply create jquery object from html like  $(your_html_with_quotes).get(0)

Answer (score 1):

You can create elements instead of html strings and set `value` property of each input element. Then that string won't be in the generated html:

```
function create(server_data) {
    return  $('<div>').append( $('<input>').val(server_data[0].videos[0].embed) )
                      .append( $('<input>').val(server_data[0].videos[1].embed) )
}

$('body').append(create(server_data));
```

Comment: The problem is that I have a class that has a lot of inner-connected methods that interact with each other and many of those methods return a string. And the main method is just a variable that slowly builds up the HTML string that I append to the DOM in the end. I guess what you are saying might work out, but I have to rewrite a ton of code just to test it out. I was hoping there was an easier way to do this. Anyway, appreciate the response.